# Referential Integrity Error Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following classes (reduced for brevity);

```
public partial class Installation : AuditableEntity<int>
{
    [Column("InstallationId")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "installationid")]
    [Key]
    public override int ID { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Device")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deviceid")]
    public int? DeviceID { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

and (again reduced for brevity);

```
 public partial class Device : AuditableEntity<int>
    {
        [Column("deviceid"), Key]
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="deviceid")]
        public override int ID { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Installation> Installations { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Shipment> Shipments { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I am trying to create a new shipment which has a device associated with it.

My update mehtod is as follows;

```
    public override void Insert(Shipment entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

        if(entity.Devices != null)
            foreach (var device in entity.Devices)
                if (device.ID != null && device.ID > 0)
                    _context.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

        _dbset.Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

In this case the devices associated with it will be existing. However I am getting the error;

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property
>   value(s) of 'Device.ID' on one end of a relationship do not match the
>   property value(s) of 'Installation.DeviceID' on the other end.

Now from drilling down when debugging the issue is that its the foreign key inside the installation object is not being set when it gets the object? (see the screen below). But the actualy Installation.Device is being set? how do I get around this pleasE?

[image: Screen grab]

Comment: Is there a reason you've made the foreign key DeviceID a `nullable` int in Installation?

Comment: Yes initially when the installation is created the device is null and gets assigned later.

Comment: Alternatively I would try explicitly setting the id, there could be some nuances around having an entity already existing but with a null value preventing auto-updating

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have reversed the correct order of your foreign key reference code. Here:

```
[ForeignKey("Device")]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deviceid")]
public int? DeviceID { get; set; }
public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
```

Should instead be

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deviceid")]
public int? DeviceID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("DeviceID")]
public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have always marked my foreign keys the other way around? what imapct and difference does this make please? As this didnt make a difference? I still get the same error.

Comment: Here, DeviceID is the actual foreign key, where you were specifying the foreign table name as the foreign key. However, you are correct in that it may still work because of the naming convention you are following (i.e. Device and DeviceID) so it still knows what the actual foreign key is. Please see my other comment for more possible fixes!

Comment: thanks for the answer below and the additional comment. Ideally I would like to try and find a generic solution for this as its built on a generic repo? Why if the ex know the entities are related isn't the fk is populated? Is there anything I can do to 'tell' ef to do this?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to explicitly set the id foreign key when you update that entry!

Comment: Sorry jonathon, I understand what you are saying, I just wonder why ef doesnt populate it automcatically hen it does this. My understanding of the situation is that if the FK ID (e.g. DeviceID) is set this is marking the entity as existing. If I were marking i DeviceID as NULL or 0 then the underlying type (Device) is marked for insertion? So in this case I have done a get of all items associated but its just populated the string types and not the ID? (let me know if that makes sense :) )

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, generally you never want to be setting foreign keys to null. If you don't have the foreign field yet perhaps you should have the foreign key on the other end? I.e. a shopping centre might add employees later so we put the shopping centre FK on the employees not an employee FK on the shopping centre. Setting it to null or not setting it will be causing this weird behaviour where it won't auto-set it afterwards like it usually does

Comment: Ok. I agree. But then if we were to gather info on the shopping centre from the employee perspective? I.e. See the centre they are working for then how would this be done if there's no relation?

Comment: There would be a relation, but from the employee side right? Because when we add an employee we know they have to have a place they work, so we can have that reference without ever setting FK to null. And from this the shipping centre will have a virtual list of employees that we can see. So we put the FK on the table that is the many in a 1 to many relationship